# Resize canvas component correctly

Tags: css, angular, canvas, styling, babylonjs

For my current project, I implement an Angular 8 library that provides a component Canvas with a canvas element. The component can be included in any Angular project using `<app-canvas [width]="canvas.width" [height]="canvas.height"></app-canvas>` in some template.

As you can see, the template contains two `@Input` properties, `width` and `height`. By executing a dynamic BabylonJS game code at runtime, it should be possible to update the Canvas component's width and height if some reference variables change.

My question is how to achieve a correct resizing of the `HTMLCanvasElement` that actually renders the images. Should the canvas element itself be resized using CSS parameters, or should it better be wrapped into a container which should handle the resizing and use the canvas only as child?

Using `ngStyle` and a parent container resulted in an "ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError":

```html
<div id="canvas-container" [ngStyle]="{'width': gameState.get('screen.width') + 'px', 'height': gameState.get('screen.height') + 'px'}">
  <canvas #canvas
          (focus)="canvasFocused = true"
          (blur)="canvasFocused = false">
  </canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Why is it required to set the height and width of the canvas parent?

Comment: Because the game script which gets executed at runtime can contain "viewport resizing" functions that affect the canvas size. In fact, the `ngStyle` could also be applied directly to the `canvas` element itself, that was part of my question whether this would be more reasonable than to encapsulate the canvas into a container.

Comment: Well if it's possible to set height and width of the canvas, then it seems pointless to have a parent unless the canvas is part of a layout :)